# header line in second page of abstract

Tags: header-footer, abstract

I'm writing my thesis. In my abstract there is two pages. So, I want a head in second page. My MWE code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Resumo}


Esta dissertação de mestrado teve como objectivo modificar partículas de carbonato de cálcio natural (GCC) através do revestimento com sílica, \textit{in situ}, seguindo a metodologia sol-gel, de modo a aumentar a resistência mecânica da folha de papel. Assim, aumenta-se a quantidade de \textit{filler} presente na folha, ocorrendo uma substituição parcial de uma matéria-prima por outra menos dispendiosa.

Foram utilizadas três gamas de GCC, testando diferentes tamanhos e brancuras, para efectuar o revestimento de sílica, seguindo a metodologia que \cite{gamelas} aplicou ao carbonato de cálcio precipitado. A reacção sol-gel decorreu em meio ácido, utilizando TEOS como percursor, a qual prolongou-se por 24 horas a uma temperatura de .

Com o intuito de caracterizar as partículas de carbonato de cálcio, original e modificado, foram efectuados diversas técnicas analíticas para analisar: a morfologia (microscopia electrónica de varrimento), o tamanho (espectroscopia de difracção laser), a composição química (espectroscopia de infravermelho por transformada de Fourier), a quantidade de sílica presente no GCC (termogravimetria), a brancura (espectrofotometria) e métodos de potencial zeta. Concluiu-se que houve deposição de sílica nas partículas de GCC, tal como era expectável.

Tal como o PCC modificado, documentado em \cite{lou}, conseguiu-se obter melhorias nas propriedades mecânicas da folha quando o \textit{filler} modificado foi aplicado, independentemente da gama utilizada, conseguindo-se concretizar um dos objectivos propostos. Esta melhoria deve-se à presença de grupos hidroxilo da sílica, que permitem estabelecer pontes de hidrogénio com as fibras de celulose. O aumento na resistência da folha ocorreu em maior grau no GCC com menor tamanho de partícula, indicativo que a deposição de sílica depende do tamanho das partículas de GCC. Relativamente às propriedades ópticas das folhas, estas foram ligeiramente prejudicas com a aplicação dos GCC's modificados, sugerindo que a folha está "fechada" devido a uma ligação \textit{filler}-fibra mais forte, sendo que no GCC com tamanho de partícula perde-se menos opacidade. Assim, constatou-se que é preferível modificar o carbonato de cálcio com menor tamanho de partícula.

Nos GCC's que se diferenciavam pelo nível de brancura, não houve diferenças a registar entre as folhas formadas por estas duas cargas minerais.

Comparou-se os resultados obtidos com GCC modificado com os de PCC, conseguidos por \cite{lou}, constatando-se que é melhor modificar PCC do que GCC. Além da tendência natural que o PCC possui para repercutir boas propriedades ópticas na folha de papel, o revestimento com sílica induziu uma melhoria nas propriedades mecânicas da folha numa magnitude superior às obtidas com GCC, ultrapassando a capacidade intrínseca que este \textit{filler} contêm neste âmbito. Este resultado foi semelhante ao obtido pela aplicação de GCC modificado correspondente a 30 \%(w/w) da folha.

Também se produziu folhas de papel com uma mistura de cargas minerais, 20 \%(w/w) GCC modificado e 10 \%(w/w) de carbonato de cálcio precipitado, com o objectivo de reduzir a quantidade de carga modificada e para melhorar as propriedades ópticas. Os resultados indicam que é preferível usar esta carga mineral do que apenas GCC modificado, isto, se tivermos em conta os custos associados à modificação.

Ao utilizar cargas modificadas, comprovou-se que é possível aumentar o conteúdo (cerca de 10 \%) de carga mineral, sem prejudicar as propriedades mecânicas das folhas de papel. Este facto foi confirmado tanto na aplicação de GCC modificado, como na de mistura de cargas, tendo este último vantagem devido à componente económica.

Como os objectivos deste estudo estão intimamente ligados a um factor económico, deverá-se estimar os custos económicos da modificação de carbonato de cálcio a fim de avaliar devidamente os resultados obtidos.

Apesar dos resultados não serem totalmente positivos na aplicação a papéis de impressão e escrita, isto é, em relação ao carbonato de cálcio precipitado, poderá ser útil em papéis com outro tipo de utilização, onde as propriedades ópticas não são fundamentais.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your chapter is starred, you will have to use the command `\chaptermark{}` here. As this chapter is chapter 0, it would result in

> CAPÍTULO 0. RESUMO

I redefined the chaptermark Command in order to get just "RESUMO" in case, the chapter is 0 or smaller. You may adapt this to your needs. I used the `\MakeUppercase{}` as this seems to be the default in your example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead,headheight=15.8pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}

% changed the text to CAPÍTULO. Here you can define whatever you want.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \markboth{CAPÍTULO \thechapter{}: \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}%
  \else
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Resumo}
\chaptermark{Resumo}

Esta dissertação de mestrado teve como objectivo modificar partículas de carbonato de cálcio natural (GCC) através do revestimento com sílica, \textit{in situ}, seguindo a metodologia sol-gel, de modo a aumentar a resistência mecânica da folha de papel. Assim, aumenta-se a quantidade de \textit{filler} presente na folha, ocorrendo uma substituição parcial de uma matéria-prima por outra menos dispendiosa.

Foram utilizadas três gamas de GCC, testando diferentes tamanhos e brancuras, para efectuar o revestimento de sílica, seguindo a metodologia que \cite{gamelas} aplicou ao carbonato de cálcio precipitado. A reacção sol-gel decorreu em meio ácido, utilizando TEOS como percursor, a qual prolongou-se por 24 horas a uma temperatura de .

Com o intuito de caracterizar as partículas de carbonato de cálcio, original e modificado, foram efectuados diversas técnicas analíticas para analisar: a morfologia (microscopia electrónica de varrimento), o tamanho (espectroscopia de difracção laser), a composição química (espectroscopia de infravermelho por transformada de Fourier), a quantidade de sílica presente no GCC (termogravimetria), a brancura (espectrofotometria) e métodos de potencial zeta. Concluiu-se que houve deposição de sílica nas partículas de GCC, tal como era expectável.

Tal como o PCC modificado, documentado em \cite{lou}, conseguiu-se obter melhorias nas propriedades mecânicas da folha quando o \textit{filler} modificado foi aplicado, independentemente da gama utilizada, conseguindo-se concretizar um dos objectivos propostos. Esta melhoria deve-se à presença de grupos hidroxilo da sílica, que permitem estabelecer pontes de hidrogénio com as fibras de celulose. O aumento na resistência da folha ocorreu em maior grau no GCC com menor tamanho de partícula, indicativo que a deposição de sílica depende do tamanho das partículas de GCC. Relativamente às propriedades ópticas das folhas, estas foram ligeiramente prejudicas com a aplicação dos GCC's modificados, sugerindo que a folha está "fechada" devido a uma ligação \textit{filler}-fibra mais forte, sendo que no GCC com tamanho de partícula perde-se menos opacidade. Assim, constatou-se que é preferível modificar o carbonato de cálcio com menor tamanho de partícula.

Nos GCC's que se diferenciavam pelo nível de brancura, não houve diferenças a registar entre as folhas formadas por estas duas cargas minerais.

Comparou-se os resultados obtidos com GCC modificado com os de PCC, conseguidos por \cite{lou}, constatando-se que é melhor modificar PCC do que GCC. Além da tendência natural que o PCC possui para repercutir boas propriedades ópticas na folha de papel, o revestimento com sílica induziu uma melhoria nas propriedades mecânicas da folha numa magnitude superior às obtidas com GCC, ultrapassando a capacidade intrínseca que este \textit{filler} contêm neste âmbito. Este resultado foi semelhante ao obtido pela aplicação de GCC modificado correspondente a \SI{30}{\percent (w/w)} da folha.

Também se produziu folhas de papel com uma mistura de cargas minerais, \SI{20}{\percent (w/w)} GCC modificado e \SI{10}{\percent (w/w)} de carbonato de cálcio precipitado, com o objectivo de reduzir a quantidade de carga modificada e para melhorar as propriedades ópticas. Os resultados indicam que é preferível usar esta carga mineral do que apenas GCC modificado, isto, se tivermos em conta os custos associados à modificação.

Ao utilizar cargas modificadas, comprovou-se que é possível aumentar o conteúdo (cerca de \SI{10}{\percent}) de carga mineral, sem prejudicar as propriedades mecânicas das folhas de papel. Este facto foi confirmado tanto na aplicação de GCC modificado, como na de mistura de cargas, tendo este último vantagem devido à componente económica.

Como os objectivos deste estudo estão intimamente ligados a um factor económico, deverá-se estimar os custos económicos da modificação de carbonato de cálcio a fim de avaliar devidamente os resultados obtidos.

Apesar dos resultados não serem totalmente positivos na aplicação a papéis de impressão e escrita, isto é, em relação ao carbonato de cálcio precipitado, poderá ser útil em papéis com outro tipo de utilização, onde as propriedades ópticas não são fundamentais.
\chapter{chapter}
% If you need to use a starred chapter again, just use a \markboth directly instead of a \chaptermark
\chapter*{starred chapter}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{starred chapter}}{}
\chapter{chapter}
% when ever you need to, you may redefine the chaptermark again.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{APÊNDICE \thechapter{}: \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\chapter{Appendix 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\setlength{\headheight}{15.8pt}` should be added (or the option `headheight=15.8pt` to `geometry`).

Comment: @egreg Done. Could you add some reference please? I guess, you didn't come up with this value by your eye...

Comment: The value to be used is printed in the log file under `Package Fancyhdr Warning`; always check warnings. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Could you explain me why I should added headheight=15.8pt ?

Comment: @user46548 If the height needed for the header is larger than the default one, `fancyhdr` will fix it from the second page where the header appears, which will give unbalanced pages and may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And How I can check the space that I need ?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thank you for your answer. But I have I problem. Now the head in "normal" chapters appears "chapter 1: bla bla" but should be appears chapter in portuguese, "capítulo "

Comment: I have appendices. If I used your answer. In appendices the head appears like this :"Chapter A: sddfgdf" but I want like I was before: "Appendice A: sdfsdf"

Comment: @user46548 Please see my edit. The "chapter" was hard coded in my preamble, changed that. The Appendix just needs a redefinition before it starts. I also added a starred chapter in case you need this.